# IBM Domino - 500 HTTP Web Server: Access Denied Exception

Tags: lotus-domino

I created a person document with a HTTP password.

In a database I have set Anonymous access to "No Access" and Default to "Author".

When I try to login to the database I get the following error:

HTTP Web Server: Access Denied Exception [/db.nsf] CN=User Name/O=Org

I used google and found some articles incl http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21194981 but they don't contain the fix. The user is not in the "deny access" server groups.

I created/updated 10 other person documents, all 10 can login without any issue.

Comment: Just "classic" Domino HTTP, no XPages.

Answer (score 0):

It WAS the deny access server issue. The person record had multiple names and one of the old names was denied.

A bit strange as the user has no issues accessing the Domino server using the Notes Client.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Notes and browser differences with multiple records, I seem to recall that Notes clients went down a view's index, and browser went up the view's index (intentionally), or vice versa.
This was intentional behavior, so that two elements could have the same name, but be devoted to one or the other client.